# Is there are way to use nodes using TikZ in a multicol environment?

Tags: tikz-pgf, multicol

see images: The first image shows a TikZ picture using "\draw" and the second image shows a Tikz picture using "\node". Is there a way make the TikZ picture like in the first image using nodes?

By the way, I am in a multicol environment and I am still a noob in LaTex.

[image]

Here is my code for the first image:

```
\chapter*{Title}
\begin{multicols}{2}

\lipsum [50]

\vspace{-2mm}   
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
    \tikz
    \draw [color=blue, line width=2.0pt] (0.0in,0.0in) rectangle (3.0in,1.5in);
    %\draw [color=setA, line width=1.5pt]  (1.0in,0.765in) circle (0.6in);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\vspace{-4mm}   

\lipsum
\end{multicols}
```

Here is my code for the second image:

```
\chapter*{Title 2}
\begin{multicols}{2}

\lipsum [50]

\vspace{-2mm}   
\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
    \tikz
    \node at (0in,0in) [rectangle, draw=blue, line width=2.0pt, minimum width=3.0in, minimum height=1.5in]  {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\vspace{-4mm}   

\lipsum

\end{multicols}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: The combination `\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \tikz` calls for trouble as it nests `tikzpicture`s. To first approximation: remove `\tikz` from your codes.